# Does the ancient Egyptian religion still have followers?

Tags: religion, ancient-egypt

The Ancient Egyptian religion was 3000 years old, and one of the oldest religion in the world. The religion had numerous gods and practices and flourished until the spread of Christianity in 4th century AD.

My question is:

Did all the followers of that religion convert?
Are there any who still follow the Ancient Egyptian religion today, in an unbroken tradition?

reference - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_religion

Comment: Well, Atenism is not exactly worshipped these days, but still highly respected by some. In particular, there is Rosicrucian museum in San Jose with a few halls dedicated to Akhenaten, including a reproduction of the famous stella of Akhenaten raising hands toward Sun's rays, etc.

Comment: I would argue this is not a question about history. In the current state, this is a question about contemporary religion. How could we revise this to a question about history? (Yes, probably should be in meta, but I can no longer log into meta).

Comment: Good try @T.E.D. - I removed the reference to Christianity; I suspect many of the adherents are now Muslim, and I think that will lead to a distraction.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace - I guess the question is very well into history. It’s about the past and its specifically about an event that happened in the past. I believe history also include religion. Appreciate if you could advise why an event happened 2000 years ago would not be classified as history.

Comment: @ Samuel Russell - My apologies if the question looks Specious. But, I would like to contradict on your comment on "fundamentally ignorant assumptions". The question arose when I was reading the Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_religion). Wikipedia also provided a reference which would help in understanding that it’s not an assumption, - Religion in Roman Egypt: Assimilation and Resistance- Frankfurter, David (1998)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After the spread of Christianity, the Ancient Egyptian religion faded away. The [last Egyptian temple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philae#Greco-Roman_era) was closed in the 6th Century AD by Byzantine emperor, Justinian. Although the old religion 'died' at the beginning of the middle ages, it still exists in different variations today. The most popular one is [Kemetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kemetism), an Egyptian neopagan religion which wants to reconstruct Ancient Egyptian beliefs. That and similar religions are spread all over the world and in Egypt, but in very small numbers.

So the simple answer to your question is yes. The Ancient Egyptian religion still exists, but it doesn't have as many followers now and it has changed since.

Comment: Interesting. Just to be clear, it appears this isn't a continuation of the old religion so much as an attempt to resurrect it from what's known of its ancient practice, long after it died. (Much like Celtic and German neo-paganisim)

Comment: Yes, it is attempt to renew ancient Egyptian religion, feel free to edit. :)

Comment: @Branko Sego- thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Upto the 6th century is a lot longer than I would have suspected.

Comment: Well it is, Philaean temple was closed in 6th century AD by emperor Justinian.. :)